# Kendo Mobile - Endless Scrolling Listview Issue in ButtonGroup

Tags: jquery, kendo-mobile

I am following Kendo's Mobile [ButtonGroup Demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/buttongroup/index.html#/) and am running into a problem.
Like the demo, I have a button group with three buttons and three listviews. Each button shows a certain listview, and hides the others. My first listview uses endless scrolling. Whenever I scroll to the bottom of the other 2 listviews, a next page request is made for the first listview, populating it. How do I prevent this?

Here's some relevant pieces of code I'm working with (all initializing of widgets is handled in my view's data-init method):

```
<ul id="buttonGroup" data-index="0">
    <li>
    Days
    </li>
    <li>
    Summary
    </li>
    <li>
    Notes
    </li>
</ul>


<ul id="endlessScrollingListView">
</ul>


<ul id="listview2">
</ul>


<ul id="listview3">
</ul>
```

Here's the custom select function for my button group upon initializing the widget:

```
var listViews = this.element.find("ul:not(#buttonGroup):first-child");
var listViewWrappers = listViews.closest(".km-listview-wrapper");


$("#buttonGroup").kendoMobileButtonGroup({
    select: function () {
    listViewWrappers.hide()
            .eq(this.selectedIndex)
            .show();
    },
    index: 0
});
```

Everything works as expected, except for the weird endless scrolling issue.